# Freeware application that shows a visual schema of a JavaDB (Derby) database

Tags: derby

I have created a JavaDB(Derby) database using Netbeans 7.1 on my mac and I am searching for a freeware application that I can use to see a picture of the full database schema with all the tables and their connections.
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked Squirrel SQL Client? - http://www.squirrelsql.org/

Comment: Great piece of software.Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are very welcome. Yes, it is wonderful ! If you have questions regarding the configuration, let me know. Also, if you are using embedded JavaDB, make sure only one instance of it is being accessed (either by your application or via Squirrel Client)

Comment: I only had to copy a derby-client jar library for it to work, but after that all is ok.